# D3 Zoom resets scales selected via brushing.

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

I've made zooming and brushing working together. The only problem is, when I've set the particular period on X axis via brushing and then trying to use zoom (on mouse drag or mouse wheel), it resets previous selected scales, so zoom doesn't store x axis domain that was set via brushing before.

```
zoomRight = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .x(xScale)
  .y(yRightScale)
  .scaleExtent([1,20])

zoomed = ->
  zoomRight.scale(zoom.scale()).translate(zoom.translate())
  canvas.select("._x._axis").call xAxis
  canvas.select(".axisLeft").call yLeftAxis
  canvas.select(".axisRight").call yRightAxis
  canvas.select(".y.grid").call make_y_axis().tickSize(-width, 0, 0).tickFormat("")
  canvas.select(".line1").attr("d", line1(data))
  canvas.select(".line2").attr("d", line2(data))
  brush.extent(xScale.domain())
  canvas.select(".brush").call(brush)

zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .x(xScale)
  .y(yLeftScale)
  .scaleExtent([1,20]) # 20x times zoom
  .on("zoom", zoomed)
```

Full code is here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p29qC/8/). How can I force zoom to remember the previous brushing selection(position)?

Comment: The zoom and brush behaviour really don't work well together in this case because they are essentially doing the same thing. You would need to set the zoom translate on brush.

Comment: Thanks, good to hear from you as always. I've disabled the zoom at all eventually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved the problem by adding the following lines on brush:

```
zoom.x(xScale)
zoom.translate()
```

Working example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p29qC/13/).